# PHP: Search objects in an array

Tags: php, arrays, object

Let's say I have an array of objects.

```
<?php

$people = array();
$people[] = new person('Walter Cook');
$people[] = new person('Amy Green');
$people[] = new person('Irene Smith');
```

How can I search an object in this array for a certain instance variable? For example, let's say I wanted to search for a person object with the name of "Walter Cook".

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://us2.php.net/in_array

Comment: @l19 `in_array()` looks for exact matches, it can't search for objects that have certain properties.

Comment: There's nothing built-in that does this, just write a `foreach` loop that compares the person's name, and breaks when it finds it.

Comment: @l19 The `in_array` function is not what I am looking for. This will only return a boolean, but the object itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends of the `person` class construction, but if it has a field `name` that keeps given names, you can get this object with a loop like this:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($people); $i++) {
    if($people[$i]->name == $search_name) {
        $person = $people[$i];
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is:

```
$requiredPerson = null;

for($i=0;$i<sizeof($people);$i++)
{
   if($people[$i]->name == "Walter Cook")
    {
        $requiredPerson = $people[$i];
        break;
    }

}

if($requiredPerson == null)
{
    //no person found with required property
}else{
    //person found :)
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `name` is a public property of the `person` class:

```
<?php

// build the array of objects
$people = array();
$people[] = new person('Walter Cook');
$people[] = new person('Amy Green');
$people[] = new person('Irene Smith');

// search name
$searchName = 'Walter Cook';

// ascertain the presence of the name in the array of objects
$isMatch = false;

foreach ($people as $person) {
    if ($person->name === $searchName) {
        $isMatch = true;
        break;
    }
}

// alternatively, if you want to return all matches into 
// a new array of $results you can use array_filter
$result = array_filter($people, function($person) use ($searchName) {
    return $person->name === $searchName;
});
```

hope this helps :)

Comment: sorry, I just saw the question has already been marked as answered while I was adding this!

Answer (score 0):

well you could try this inside your class

```
    //the search function
function search_array($array, $attr_name, $attr_value) {
    foreach ($array as $element) {
        if ($element -> $attr_name == $attr_value) {
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
    return FALSE;
}

//this function will test the output of the search_array function
function test_Search_array() {
    $person1 = new stdClass();
    $person1 -> name = 'John';
    $person1 -> age = 21;

    $person2 = new stdClass();
    $person2 -> name = 'Smith';
    $person2 -> age = 22;
    $test = array($person1, $person2);
    //upper/lower case should be the same
    $result = $this -> search_array($test, 'name', 'John');
    echo json_encode($result);
}
```